# Multiple USB devices failing to install

Tags: windows-8, usb, drivers

I recently bought an audio interface (Presonus Audiobox USB) and had trouble installing it on my computer. At first, I thought the problem came from the sound card itself because the drivers didn't seem to be compatible with Windows 8.

Now, I tried to plug my Samsung Galaxy S3 in it today and I was surprised to see that the process was exactly the same, so I'm thinking the problem could be due to either my Windows setup or my hardware.

Basically, when I plug a device (either the sound card or the phone), it starts installing itself like it normally should. After a few seconds, the installation window disappears without any error message. After checking the device manager, it seems that the device is not properly installed (Code 1 error, not configured correctly).

In the case of my Audiobox sound card, I can't even install the official Presonus drivers after the Windows 8 installation has failed, the only error message I get is that "something could not be executed" (even in compatibility mode).

Where could this problem come from? Is it due to my USB port drivers? Is it a Windows 8 issue?

I have to add that all my USB ports (2xUSB3 + 2xUSB2) seem to work perfectly fine when plugging a keyboard or mouse for example.

Any hint on solving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot !

Here are the specs of my laptop :

```
ASUS N55SF
Windows 8 Pro 64-bit (initially Windows 7 with ASUS bloatware when I bought it)
Intel Core i7-2670QM
CPU @ 2.20Ghz
6,0GB RAM
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have some older instances of this device still installed in a failed state. Firstly you need to check for these non-present instances in your device manager as follows. Make sure your USB device is not plugged in first.

First, configure Device Manager to show non-present devices:

1. Control panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment
   variables
2. Create a **system variable** named **DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES**, with a value of **1*
3. Click OK many times until you're back into Control Panel -> System
4. Open Device Manager
5. View -> Show hidden devices

You can now see disconnected / non-present devices in the form of a faded icon. Delete all of these that relate to your devices that don't install properly. If you get a tick box about "Remove device software too" then ensure you tick that.

Once you're sure all non-present devices have been removed that relate to this, plug in your USB device again.

Comment: I actually did try this a couple of times already (no need to create a system variable, you have the "show hidden devices" access directly in the menu) and it didn't solve the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: "Show hidden devices" is always available, but usually the option will only allow you to see devices that Microsoft don't think you need to see. If you add the environment variable this show hidden devices will also show you devices previously connected to your system but no longer are.

Comment: Ok I see. I tried to create a system variable but it didn't reveal any hidden device, so I guess my problem isn't caused by a failed state.

Comment: Disconnected devices should show up with a faded out hardware icon. If you don't see any something isn't working :s

Comment: Yes they should and they do, but since I had uninstalled all the "Audiobox USB" instances nothing is left, which is normal. So I didn't have any previous device installed.

Comment: Pls note in Windows 8, Microsoft has removed the ability to see non present devices. So basically DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES has no effect on Windows 8, adding it to environment variables may actually screw up something. This is why "morgi" commented that adding it to system variable didn't reveal any hidden devices.